# Unable to resolve service when using DI

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I am attempting to implement a Repository pattern and make use of Dependency Injection.  In the code below I have a Genmeric Repository interface and class from which other repository interfaces and classes are derived from, the example below InvestmentTransactionRepository.

In my GenericRepository class I am attempting to DI the application dbContext.

Code:

Interfaces/IGenericRepository.cs

```
namespace WebApi.Shared.Interfaces
{
    public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
    }
}
```

Interfaces/IInvestmentTransactionRepository.cs

```
namespace WebApi.Shared.Interfaces
{
    public interface IInvestmentTransactionRepository : IGenericRepository<InvestmentTransactionEntity>
    {
    }
}
```

/Repositories/GenericRepository.cs

```
using WebApi.Shared.Interfaces;

namespace WebApi.Shared.Repositories
{
    public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        protected readonly AccountingContext _context;

        public GenericRepository(AccountingContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    }
}
```

/Repositories/InvestmentTransactionRepository.cs

```
namespace WebApi.Shared.Repositories
{
    public class InvestmentTransactionRepository : GenericRepository<InvestmentTransactionEntity>, IInvestmentTransactionRepository
    {
        public InvestmentTransactionRepository(AccountingContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

/Controllers/InvestmentController.cs

```
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class InvestmentsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private Services.IUserService _userService;
        private Shared.Repositories.InvestmentTransactionRepository _investmentTransactionRepository;

        public InvestmentsController(Services.IUserService userService, 
                                     WebApi.Shared.Repositories.InvestmentTransactionRepository investmentTransactionRepository)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            _investmentTransactionRepository = investmentTransactionRepository;
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost("list")]
        public IActionResult List(RequestContext.Investment.ListDto request)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

/AccountingContext.cs

```
namespace WebApi.Shared
{
    public class AccountingContext : DbContext
    {
        public AccountingContext()
        {
        }

        public AccountingContext(DbContextOptions<AccountingContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            // hidden
        }
    }
}
```

/Program.cs

```
services.AddScoped<AccountingContext>();
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
services.AddScoped<IInvestmentEntityRepository, InvestmentEntityRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IInvestmentTransactionRepository, InvestmentTransactionRepository>();
```

When I run the above, the build is succesfull but the following error is produced at run time:

Unable to resolve service for type "WebApi.Shared.Repositories.InvestmentTransactionRepository" while attempting to activate "WebApi.Controllers.InvestmentsController"

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just to add to @SBFrancies' answer, some explanation.  Let's say that later your website gets massive, and you need to change the way you store and retrieve your data.  You will keep the same INTERFACE, but change the IMPLEMENTATION, maybe greatly, with a new class.  But none of the 100 components that reference `IInvestmentTransactionRepository` need to know that, since the interface never changes.  So you will create the new class to implement your interface, change ONE LINE in the startup for your app, and walk away.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 This is a solid explanation and being new to C# and this pattern in general, your comment did help provide some useful understanding into why Interfaces are valuable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding `IInvestmentTransactionRepository`,the interface, to the container but attempting to inject and resolve `WebApi.Shared.Repositories.InvestmentTransactionRepository`, the class. You should either add the class to the container or (better) inject the interface.